# How do newHeads and event subscriptions behave on past reorgs?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, events

Based on the [geth documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/RPC-PUB-SUB), I understand that a subscription on both newHeads and logs will emit all new heads and events that come from a reorg. However, I couldn't find what the behaviour is when reorg occurs *after* the client subscribed, but forking from a block *before* the one of the subscription.

For example:

```
1.
A -> B -> C
Client subscribes after block C

2.
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
Client receives heads and events from D and E

3.
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
 \-> B'-> C'-> D'-> E'-> F'
Reorg after block A
```

In the scenario above, on step 3:

- Will the client receive the newHeads for just `D',E',F'`, or `B',C'` as well?
- Will the client receive the events from just `D',E',F'`, or `B',C'` as well?
- Will the client receive the **removed** events for just `D,E`, or `B,C` as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would love this question to be answered or at least some hints or links to documentation since I'm facing a similar problem.

Any help will be appreciated!